# How to make the state update in React with the last added task?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-sortable-hoc

I am building a simple todo app and after I have implemented react-sortable-hoc - which if you dont know is a plugin for react that implements drag and drop - the todos list doesnt update with the last added todo anymore. I dont get any kind of error in the console.

I tried to use the state that is sorted in the react-sortable-hoc onSortEnd function, but then I get Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance error.

[This is the application an codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/task-maker-djr82)

I want to make the state update with the lattest added todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has 2 issues that I can see:

1) In `Form.js`, you are not actually setting the state to the new array which contains the latest value when the form submits.  In your `handleSubmit` function you'd need to call `setState(createNewTask(value))` rather than just `createNewTask(value)`.

2) You are using a separate piece of state called `alteredState` to actually create your list and initializing it with the `tasks` array in your main state.  However, you are not updating this second array when the primary array is changed, as the value passed into `useState` is only set once on mount.  You can use a `useEffect` hook to update your secondary state when the first is changed:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setAlteredState(state.tasks);
  }, [state]);
```

Fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/task-maker-oygs5?fontsize=14).

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you Rutherford. It is so obvious now that you pointed it out.